# How do I print a character variable within quotes using php function

Tags: php

I need to get this output.

```
 the result is"random"safdsaf
```

I am using this piece of code

```
<?php

$x = "random";
echo 'the result is' .$x. 'safdsaf';
?>
```

But i am getting this

```
the result israndomsafdsaf
```

I have to define random before printing it.

i.e. I do not want to change this piece of code

```
<?php

$x = "random";
```

What change should i make inside echo to get the desired output?

Comment: you want to see the quotes after its printed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the same type of quotes delimit the quotes in your string like this:

```
echo "The result is\"" .$x. "\"safdsaf";
```

or simply use two sets of different quotes:

```
echo 'the result is"' .$x. '"safdsaf';
```

Output of either line of code:

```
The result is"random"safdsaf
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Added the little bit space befor ' and added ", it will give the some out put as you want

```
echo 'the result is "' .$x. '" safdsaf';
```

the result will be

```
The result is "random" safdsaf
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print out double quotes you can include them in single quotes
Something like this would do the trick.

```
$x = '"random"';
```

If for whatever reason you don't want to use single quotes you can also escape them like :

```
$x = "\"random\"";
```

As you want to keep the string, I suggest you change the original line where you put it in :

```
echo 'the result is"' .$x. '"safdsaf';
```

the principle stays the same 
Here's some reading material : http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use simply :-

```
echo 'the result is "' .$x. '" safdsaf';
```

OR you can use .

```
echo "the result is \" $x\"  safdsaf";
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `\` before the quote like this: `the result is \"random\" safdsaf`.
if you have alot of quotes and such in a string, i would suggest using the `addslashes()`. This method will do the work for you for you.
For more info, take a look here - http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_addslashes.asp